# Решение уравнения 4-й степени

Tags: математика

Подскажите пожалуйста, как найти корни данного конкретного уравнения относительно *a*?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует максимально возможный простой метод решения.

Предполагаю, что найти корни можно, разбив на три этапа.

**Первый** – поиск некоторой подходящей замены переменных, при которой уравнение превратится в квадратное.
**Второй** – решение квадратного уравнения, нахождение корней.
**Третий** – нахождение изначально искомых корней через выражение замены.

Если ход мыслей правильный, то не могли бы подсказать как реализовать первый этап?
Примеры можно как формулами, так и на любом языке.

Wolfram Alpha выдаёт этот [результат](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:a%5E4-6*a%5E2*b-8*a*c-3*b%5E2%2F%2F%5D%7D,+%7B%5B%2F%2Fmath:a%2F%2F%5D%7D%5D).

Comment: "максимально возможный простой метод" - I love you! добавьте еще "правильный" в список критериев

Comment: не превратится оно в квадратное)

Comment: хочется стремиться к простому решению

Comment: Выбирайте: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8

Comment: http://www.resolventa.ru/spr/algebra/ferrary.htm

Comment: А что в данном уравнении является неизвестными, а что константами?

Comment: @Yaant неизвестное `a`, остальное константы

Comment: Решите его как квадратное относительно `b`, возможно, получите разложение в произведение более простых выражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый **простой** - запускаем Mathematica...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]